# What is the fastest algorithm for counting points in elliptic curves mod n?

Tags: elliptic-curves

I need an algorithm for getting the order of the group in random elliptic curves mod n, being n a composite module. As far as I know, usual algorithms like Schoof's algorithm only works with prime modulus. What are the alternatives?

Comment: Sort of converse to Felipe's answer: If the factorisation of $n$ is known then it suffices to find the number of points on the curve modulo the prime factors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't expect that there will be a known polynomial time algorithm. If I recall correctly, we don't know a polynomial time algorithm to decide, given $n=pq \equiv 1 \pmod 4, p,q$ primes, whether $p,q \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ or not. If we had a polynomial time algorithm to compute the number of points in $y^2 =x^3+x \pmod n$ we could decide the previous problem (as the number of points would be $(p+1)(q+1)$ when $p,q \equiv 3 \pmod 4$). Even better, if we knew that $p,q \equiv 3 \pmod 4$, we would then factor $n$.

If you have a point on the curve (of reasonably large order), baby-step-giant-step will be a $\sqrt n$ algorithm.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residuosity_problem

Answer (score 1):

Let the group order be $o$.

If $o$ is odd, you can factor $n$ in polynomial time
(I am pretty sure this will work for even $o$ too).

Let $\psi_k$ be the k-th division polynomial of $E$
and $p$ a prime factor of $n$.

Choose random $x_0 \in [1,n]$ and compute
$\psi_o(x_0)\equiv a \pmod{n}$.

If $x_0$ is on the curve modulo $p$, $a$ is zero modulo $p$, otherwise
it is non-zero.

So if $x_0$ is on the curve modulo $p$, but not on it modulo
some other factor, you find multiple of $p$.

The probability of being on the curve modulo $p$ is about $\frac12$.

Comment: I guess that works if the number of points on the curve modulo $p$ differs from the number of points on the quadratic twist of the the curve modulo $p$ for every $p|n$. If the opposite holds for every $p$ (i.e the number of points is $p+1$) then we also factor $n$ as in my answer. I don't see what happens in the mixed situation.

Comment: @FelipeVoloch I am ready to bet modification of this will work for even $o$. In my answer $x_0$ is $X$ coordinate on either the curve or on the quadratic twist. Having non-singular curve modulo $n$ and the order is enough for factoring IMHO. What do you mean by "mixed situation"? I would just try another $x_0$.

Comment: The issue is not even or odd o, I think that's ok. The problem is if the number of points on the curve mod p is p+1. If it is also true for q that the number of points is q+1, you need to use my method instead. The mixed situation is when this happens for p but not for q and it's not clear to me what happens then.

Comment: @FelipeVoloch I would use my method enough times to ensure for all p the order is $p+1$. Then for all $p$ I know multiple of $p+1$, which is trivial modification of the $p+1$ factoring algorithm.